# Buildfarm failures for Kinetic "move_base_to_manip"

Tags: ros, jenkins, move-group-interface, binary

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd appreciate some help clearing up these [build failures](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_to_manip) (click on Jenkins jobs (13)). I hate to be the cause of multiple failures. The buildfarm output with some numbered error messages follows. I'm confused about multiple things:

- What would be the cause of a source build passing, but a binary build failing?
- Message 1 is internal to move_group and not something caused by my repo, correct?
- Is the buildfarm pulling my [latest Kinetic release](https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/move_base_to_manip/releases)? I don't think so, because it should have fixed Messages 2-8. (Mostly because I [switched from move_group to move_group_interface](https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/move_base_to_manip/commit/4a23039bd4d0ac63ef970e51210f9f465902b42a))
- No need to worry about Message #8. I'll [change that to a proper service call](https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/move_base_to_manip/commit/0b4184b21e4028b7d3eaf60cd02360f0571b931d) when I know how to fix these other issues.
- Thanks!

---

**Message 1**

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h: In member function ‘const ModelSharedPtr& robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader::getSRDF() const’:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h:120:12: error: ‘rdf_loader_’ was not declared in this scope
     return rdf_loader_->getSRDF();
```

**Message 2**

```
In file included from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp:4:0:
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/include/move_base_to_manip.h: At global scope:
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/include/move_base_to_manip.h:13:195: warning: ‘MoveGroup’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   const double cartesian_motion(const std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose>& waypoints, moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory& trajectory, moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup& moveGroup, ros::NodeHandle& nh);
```

**Message 3**

```
In file included from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/include/move_base_to_manip.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:56:7: note: declared here
 class MoveGroup : public MoveGroupInterface
```

**Message 4**

```
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp:87:213: warning: ‘MoveGroup’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 const double move_base_to_manip::cartesian_motion(const std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose>& waypoints, moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory& trajectory, moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup& moveGroup, ros::NodeHandle &nh)
```

**Message 5**

```
In file included from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/include/move_base_to_manip.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:56:7: note: declared here
 class MoveGroup : public MoveGroupInterface
```

**Message 6**

```
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp:111:68: warning: ‘MoveGroup’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup moveGroup( move_group_name );
```

**Message 7**

```
In file included from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/include/move_base_to_manip.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:56:7: note: declared here
 class MoveGroup : public MoveGroupInterface
```

**Message 8**

```
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp: In function ‘const double move_base_to_manip::cartesian_motion(const std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > >&, moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory&, moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup&, ros::NodeHandle&)’:
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-move-base-to-manip-1.0.6/src/move_base_to_manip.cpp:92:45: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int system(const char*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     system("rosservice call /clear_octomap");
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256241/buildfarm-failures-for-kinetic-%22move_base_to_manip%22/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

DT helped me figure out how to handle the splitting of a branch. The devel_branch parameter in tracks.yaml of the release repo needs to be updated from e.g. 'null' to 'indigo'.

Now there's just that move_group error to figure out...

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-03-06**:
Can you please clarify which message # is still unclear.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-03-06**:
Message #1

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-03-06**:
The error happens when your code includes `robot_model_loader.h`. The upstream code looks good. So it might be related to the code using it. Have you successfully build the same code locally? Can you post more context around the error message? Can you link to the failing job?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-03-08**:
Yes, I did build it locally with `catkin_make` & `catkin build`. And it builds even with "robot_model_loader.h" commented. Hmm.. well, problem solved. I will just remove that header.